# How To Get IPython Notebook To Run Python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Python to bear with me.

1. I installed Anaconda, works great.
2. I setup a Python 3 environment following the Anaconda [cmd line instructions](http://continuum.io/blog/anaconda-python-3), works great.
3. I [setup Anaconda's Python 3 environment as Pycharm's interpreter](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/ide_integration.html), works great.
4. I launched the [Anaconda "launcher.app"](http://docs.continuum.io/_images/Anaconda_Launcher.png) and launched IPython Notebook. However, iPython Notebook is running Python 2 not 3.

Over three hours of Googling later, I cannot figure out how to set IPython Notebook to run Python 3 instead of 2.

Comment: You need to launch it from your Python 3 environment. That's easy at a command line (`/path/to/env/bin/ipython`), but I don't know how to do it from the Anaconda GUI launcher.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. For future searchers, here was the solution: export PATH=/Users/[insertusername]/anaconda/envs/py3k/bin:$PATH
ipython notebook

Comment: SO should let you answer your own question after a while, so it's clear from search results that it was resolved.

Answer (score 112):

To set IPython Notebook to run Python 3 instead of 2 on my MAC 10.9, I did the following steps

```
$ sudo pip3 install ipython[all]
```

Then

```
$ ipython3 notebook
```

Comment: You shouldn't ever have to use `sudo` with `pip` (or `pip3`)

Comment: Why `[all]` on the end? `pip3 install ipython` worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

For linux 16.04 Ubuntu you can use

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3
```

and then use

```
ipython3 notebook
```

to open the notebook in the browser. If you have any notebooks saved with python 2 then it will automatically convert them to Python 3 once you open the notebook.

Answer (score 6):

To use jupyter with python 3 instead of python 2 on my Windows 10 with Anaconda, I did the following steps on anaconda prompt:

```
pip3 install ipython[all]
```

Then,

```
ipython3 notebook
```

Answer (score 4):

Is there a package from your distro? If you're using ubuntu you must to install the ipython3-notebook package.
If not, maybe you must to install ipython with python3.

If you've run (because it's python2 by default)

```
python setup.py
```

you must to run instead

```
python3 setup.py install
```

to install a package with python3 instead python2.
This will be a new instalation of ipython3.

Answer (score 1):

In Anaconda "launcher.app" there is “Environment:” pull down menu. 
The default environment is called "root". In order to launch application using another environment, just select the desired environment from the list, to make it active.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running anaconda, then the preferred way to install notebook/jupyter is using conda:

```
conda install jupyter
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have both version available on jupyter notebook, you can change the kernel from menu.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the role of 2 and 3 in this answer as appropriate.

Say you already have jupyter setup with a python 2 kernel and an anaconda environment with python 3. Activate the python 3 enviroment and then run

```
conda install ipykernel
```

After that you can select both a 2 and 3 kernel when creating a new notebook, or in a running notebook from the kernels menu.

Answer (score -5):

Another solution would be to create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/#usage) with python3:

From this environment, install tensorflow (the version you prefer) there:

```
pip install tensorflow
```

Run your jupyter from there !