# Ipython3 notebook in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter-notebook

I have been using Ipython notebook in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. I have the latest version of Python 3 but I see that notebook runs in older version of Python 2. Then I installed ipython3 by the command `sudo apt-get install ipython3` and in the terminal ipython3 is running fine. But I see that ipython notebook has not been installed default with this. So, when I type `sudo apt-get install ipython3-notebook` in terminal it shows an error message like the following:

```
     ipython3-notebook : Depends: ipython3 (= 0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1) but 0.12.1+dfsg-0ubuntu1 is to be  installed
     E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any solution how to install ipython notebook in Python 3 ?

Comment: This link might help you, question already answered:

[Link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20360293/how-to-get-ipython-notebook-to-run-python-3

Comment: I have seen this answer but unable to launch the notebook. That's why I had to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered the same problem.

It' seems to be due to the fact the package manager have to choose between version of ipython3 packages (backports and release e.g https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+package/ipython3 )

I've solve the issue by specifying the version:

```
sudo apt-get install ipython3=0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1
sudo apt-get install ipython3-notebook=0.13.2-1~ubuntu12.04.1
```

Comment: Since this post, this has changed to  ` sudo apt-get install ipython3-notebook
`